# How to change the length of line in drawable resource?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I used the following xml code to draw a drawable image:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topRightRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" />
            <solid
                 android:color="@color/black" />
            <padding
                 android:left="0dp"
                 android:top="0dp"
                 android:right="0dp"
                 android:bottom="0dp" />
            <size
                 android:width="60dp"
                 android:height="60dp" />
           </shape>
     </item>

     <item>
        <rotate
             android:fromDegrees="45"
             android:toDegrees="45"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%">

            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                      android:width="2dp"
                     android:color="@color/white" />
               </shape>
          </rotate>
     </item>
</layer-list>
```

By the above code, I ended up with this image: 
[image]

Now I have to reduce the length of the white line in the center of the circle. i have used both `<size android:height="40dp" />` and `<size android:width="40dp" />` on the line and it doesn't do anything. So, how can I reduce the length of the line?

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: have u seen the 45% titled white line on the circle? I want to reduce the length of it?

Comment: @eegooDeveloper try posted answer

Comment: @KalpeshRupani thanks. it worked. I had to remove `@dimen` in your answer.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

Add bottom,top,end & start to your item

```
 <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:end="10dp"
        android:start="10dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%">

            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/white" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />
            <size
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:end="10dp"
        android:start="10dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="45">

            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust padding of rectangle shape to reduce the  width of line

You can try this code

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:topRightRadius="30dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"

            android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="@color/black" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
        <size
            android:width="60dp"
            android:height="60dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"

        android:pivotY="50%">

        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```